# Javascript: How to tell if a span is the first thing in a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, paragraph

I am an objective C programmer, and I need some Javascript in my latest project. One week ago I had never worked on any javascript. I have spent a few hours on this particular problem and can't figure it out. I know virtually nothing about javascript, so I apologise in advance if I make any basic errors (very likely).

Basically I have an html page. There are a number of custom span tags in the page. I need a function that tells me if any particular span tag is the first thing (not just the first span) in a paragraph. e.g. if the html looks like this:

```
<p><span class="myClass">The</span> quick brown fox jumps over the lazy <span class="myClass">dog.</span></p>
```

And then I use

```
var spanList = Document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
```

I need a function that would return TRUE for

```
isFirstInParagraph(spanList[0]);  //ie. the word "The"
```

and FALSE for

```
isFirstInParagraph(spanList[1]);  // ie. the word "dog."
```

And in the following case, both spans will return FALSE, since neither are the first thing in the paragraph.:

```
<p>The <span class="myClass">quick</span> brown fox jumps over the lazy <span class="myClass">dog.</span></p>
```

I would love to attach some semi working code, but nothing I have done has come close. It seems to me that one way to approach this would be to find range offset of the SPAN relative to the paragraph, and see if it is zero. But I have spent hours reading through documentation and can't figure it out. I can't help but think that it is because my lack of understanding of the general concepts and terms in javascript/html.

Things that might be relevant:

- paragraphs may or may not have the first word inset.
- not all myClass spans are necessarily in a paragraph, they could be in a heading for example.
- the myClass span could be in italics or bold etc..
- this needs to be javascript not query.
- it is for inside a native iOS app, in a UIWebview. I would assume something Safari compatible will work.

thanks in advance

Comment: Getting all spans and then testing their position is the wrong approach.  Just check that the first child of the paragraph is a span element, but do be aware this could be misleading if there's invisible whitespace between the `<p>` and `<span>` tags.

Comment: Thanks Alnitak. I am having to iterate through all the spans anyway, to get other information about them (that I didn't include in my question), so I figure this is probably the appropriate place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get list of all spans like that:

```
spanList = document.getElementsByTagName("span"); // all spans in document
```

Then function should look like that:

```
function isFirstInParagraph(span)
    {
        var p = span.parentNode;

        if (p.nodeName === "P") // is span contained within 'p'
        {
            if (p.firstChild === span)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I tried this, but seems to returning if the span is the first of a number of spans in the paragraph. I think perhaps I wasn't clear about what I wanted, so I have edited the question. I need to to return true only if it is the very first thing in the paragraph, not just the first span. thanks anyway.

Comment: By thing you mean first tag or first text. If you have <p>text<span>dog</span> and ask for that span do you expect false?

Comment: I edited my answer. Now it only returns true if span you ask for is very first character in paragraph.

Comment: You are taking all spans, so there can be same outerHTML span in one paragraph. Your code will return true for both span from this paragraph `<p><span>x</span>somethings here<span>x</span></p>`. I prefer to take first child node and compare objects.

Comment: now you're missing the if (p.innerHTML.indexOf(span.outerHTML) === 0) part

Comment: That's OK it is no longer needed p.firstChild === span works the same plus returns false for second span if it is exactly the same as first one.

Comment: Ah I see. I have some other strange things happening that are probably not anything to do with your code. For some reason I need to save the html after inserting a span for this version to report correctly (otherwise I get false negatives), but the last version of your function reported correctly immediately without saving the html first. Strange. No problem though, as I have just told it to auto save each time I insert a tag and now it works correctly. (although a bit concerning that I don't know why I have to do this)

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell from a little testing I seem to be getting false negatives if the paragraph starts with formatted text like italics, does that sound right? For example this would report false, whereas it should be true e.g.  <p><i><span class="myClass">The</span></i> quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by 'save html' it might be because previous version was comparing raw text while new compares objects (firstChild). Looks like object is not updated after insert unless you save...

Regarding second question - yes it is correct. If you put your span within <i> that <i> becomes first child. You may consider setting italic in your css class definition.

Comment: Update: It turns out the "save html" fix wasn't working, and it is only when I reload the page that the second version works. So I have gone back to the first version you posted. This is ok for my use, as I realised that there can never be two spans as the first two things in a paragraph, as (because of my other code) span contents are always words, and by definition there must be a space between them. I have also made a recursive version that seems to work for the cases where there are italics etc. I'm not sure if I should use capitals (p.nodeName === "BODY") or (p.nodeName === "body")?

Comment: `function isFirstInParagraph(span) 
{
    var p = span.parentNode;
    
    if (p.innerHTML.indexOf(span.outerHTML) === 0)
        
    {
        if (p.nodeName === "P") // is span contained within 'p'
            return true;
        
        else if (p.nodeName === "BODY") //if it gets are far as "body" then its not in a paragraph
            return false;
        
        else return isFirstInParagraph(p); //recursion
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}`

Comment: I've re-marked this as the accepted answer, even though I used a variation of it as in the comments. I also clicked the up arrow, but I think someone else clicked the down and cancelled it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A function, in supporting browsers, to find *all* `span` elements that are the first-child of their respective parents:

```
function allFirstChildSpans () {
    return document.querySelectorAll('span:first-child');
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ghcv6/).

A function to test if a *given* `span` element is the first-child of its parent:

```
function isFirstChild(elem) {
    return null === elem.previousSibling;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ghcv6/7/).

Given that you want to only test if the `span` is the very first childNode of its parent, that's actually far simpler:

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ghcv6/2/).

```
function isFirstChild(elem) {
    return elem.firstChild === elem;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ghcv6/6/).

And a simple prototype-extension to add the `isFirstChild()` method to individual `HTMLElement` nodes:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.isFirstChild = function () {
    return this.parentNode.firstChild === this;
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ghcv6/5/).

Comment: just heads-up, you are not using the `allChildren` variable

Comment: @Gaby: thanks, that was a first-thoughts solution, since edited with corrected code.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I don't think I explained myself clearly, I have edited my question. This seems to return if a span is the first child in a paragraph, but I want it to return if it is the VERY first thing, including any text. So for example both spans here should return false: <p>The <span class="myClass">quick</span> brown fox jumps over the lazy <span class="myClass">dog.</span></p>

Comment: And out of interest, I had to use the "browsers that don't support previousElementChild" version to get it to work from my iOS app.

Comment: @narco: in which case the last code-snippet should do what you need; though I'm a little surprised that you're concerned about white-space/empty text-nodes being a previousSibling.

Comment: This seems to be returning TRUE if I have a single span in the middle of a paragraph. I only want it to return true if it is the first word (or punctuation etc) of a paragraph. See my edited question for an example.

Comment: Removed the `while ()` based solution since it didn't add anything and the replacement (and subsequent methods) are far simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore pure text (*not is a tag*) before the span then you can use

```
function isFirstInParagraph(span){
    var parent = span.parentNode;
    return parent.getElementsByTagName('*')[0] === span;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/gd2q9/